# Null pointer exception from adding Lines to a LineMap in lejos, cant find

Tags: pointers, exception, nullpointerexception, null, lego-mindstorms

Im having trouble finding a null pointer exception in some lejos code, which is for the EV3 lego robot. 
Below is the class state and constructor:

```
public class Mapper {

private LineMap CurrentMap;
private Line[] lines;
private boolean[] userDrawn;
private Rectangle boundary = new Rectangle(0, 0, 594, 891);
private int counter;

/**
 * Initializes an empty map with just a boundary
 * 
 * @author Ben
 */
public Mapper(){

    counter = 0;
    lines = new Line[counter];
    userDrawn = new boolean[counter];
    CurrentMap = new LineMap(lines,boundary);

}
```

And the function causing me grief

```
public void addLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, boolean isUserDrawn){
    counter++;
    Line[] oldLines = lines;
    boolean[] oldUserDrawn = userDrawn;
    lines = new Line[counter];
    userDrawn = new boolean[counter];

    for(int i = 0; i < counter - 1; i++){
        lines[i] = oldLines[i];
        userDrawn[i] = oldUserDrawn[i];
    }

    lines[counter-1] = new Line(x1,y1,x2,y2);
    if(isUserDrawn == true){
        userDrawn[counter - 1] = true;
    }
    else{
        userDrawn[counter - 1] = false;
    }
    CurrentMap = new LineMap(lines,boundary);
}
```

Any ideas for what might be a source of a null pointer exception:

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry, problem not in this code. And has been solved.